# How can I send a json data along with a file in a curl request to handle by Flask?

Tags: php, python, json, curl, flask

Problem:

I want to send a file with `-F` option and along with a json data with `-d` to the flask route.But only either i can implement.

Code I tried.

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://192.168.150.113/test

Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/test',methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.data
data = json.loads(data)
return 'success'
```

With only File :

```
curl -X POST -F file=@sample.txt http://192.168.150.113/test
@app.route('/process' , methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.files['file']
if f:
    try:
filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
f.save( os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename ))
return 'success'
```

But without sending seperate request I want to combine these two POST request and handle using flask..

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the -F option to send data with `multipart/form-data`

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@sample.txt" -F "username=xyz" -F "password=xyz" http://localhost:5000/test
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send file with json together as they have different `Content-Type`. Alternatively, you can stringify your json and send them with `multipart/form-data`. For example, you can send a `form` like the following:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@sample.txt" -F "json_data='{\"username\":\"xyz\",\"password\":\"xyz\"}'" http://localhost:5000/test
```

And in python, you can get this json by `request.form.get("json_data")`. It is more robust than passing key-value pairs through plain `multipart/form-data` as it support much more complicated structure.